# Changing a flag based on a boolean

Tags: c#, enums, binary, flags

Does any have a more elegant way of doing this?

```
[Flags]
public enum SomeFlaggedEnum
{
    Value1 = 1,
    Value2 = 2,
    Value3 = 4
}


private SomeFlaggedEnum _myFlags;

public bool EnabledValue1
{
    set 
    {
        if (value)
        {
            _myFlags |= SomeFlaggedEnum.Value1;
        }
        else
        {
            _myFlags &= ~SomeFlaggedEnum.Value1;
        }
    }
}
```

I know there is probably a simple answer and I'm just way over thinking it...

EDIT: The enum was incorrect as pointed out in one of the answers. This was only in this example and not in the actual code.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850873/enum-hasflag-why-no-enum-setflag

Comment: what about a ternary operator instead of setting property?

Comment: @Adam: I got a  discussion with guys arround what is "elegant" code here on SO. The elegant code is the code that is easy to read and understand. So I think you have already an elegant solution.

Comment: True, but if you have a lot of these things, a more compact representation may be more desirable.  But you can always just #region them and compact them in the IDE, so, yeah, whatever.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I mean, you could do:

```
_myFlags = value ? myFlags | SomeFlaggedEnum.Value1 : myFlags & ~SomeFlaggedEnum.Value1;
```

But I think your solution is fine.

Answer (score 6):

Well, you could use a conditional:

```
_myFlags = value ? _myFlags | SomeFlaggedEnum.Value1
                 : _myFlags & ~SomeFlaggedEnum.Value1;
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it'd get pretty ugly if you had a property per flag for setting it, assuming you'll have more than 3 flags. Would it not be easier to go for a single method where you can say which flags to set?

```
public void EnableFlag(SomeFlaggedEnum value, bool set) {
    _myFlags = set ? value | _myFlags : ~value & _myFlags;
}
```

---

```
EnableFlag(SomeFlaggedEnum.Value1, true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Make a generic setter for flags (there is already a generic "HasFlag" in the Enum class, but an extension like this will complement it.

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static T SetFlags<T>(this T value, T flags, bool on) where T : struct
    {    
        long lValue = Convert.ToInt64(value);
        long lFlag = Convert.ToInt64(flags);
        if (on)
        {
            lValue |= lFlag;
        }
        else
        {
            lValue &= (~lFlag);
        }
        return (T)Enum.ToObject(typeof(T), lValue);
    }
}
```

Once you have that, you can make properties for each flag (but that quickly gets messy), or simply delegate getting and setting flags to HasFlag/SetFlag

Comment: This should be the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your setter is fine.

The issue is that using `FlagsAttribute` doesn't make the compiler choose useful values for using the enum members as flags.  `SomeFlaggedEnum.Value1` is zero, because it's the first declared value in the enumeration, and so it doesn't represent a bit flag at all.

Try

```
[Flags]
public enum SomeFlaggedEnum
{
    Value1 = 1,
    Value2 = 2,
    Value3 = 4
}
```