# Applying MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining to F# functions

Tags: .net, f#, jit, cil, inlining

The attribute `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImplAttribute` can be used to give hints to the JIT compiler about how to handle the decorated method. In particular, the option `MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining` instructs the compiler to inline the affected method if possible. Unfortunately the F# compiler seems to simply ignore this attribute when generating IL.

Example: The following C# code

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
public static int Inc(int x) => x + 1;
```

is translated to

```
.method public hidebysig static int32  Inc(int32 x) cil managed aggressiveinlining
{     
    .maxstack  8
    IL_0000:  ldarg.0
    IL_0001:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_0002:  add
    IL_0003:  ret
}
```

Note the "aggressiveinlining" flag.

This F# code however

```
[<MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)>]
let inc x = x + 1
```

becomes

```
.method public static int32  inc(int32 x) cil managed
{
    .maxstack  8
    IL_0000:  nop
    IL_0001:  ldarg.0
    IL_0002:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_0003:  add
    IL_0004:  ret
}
```

No "aggressiveinlining". I also tried to apply the attribute to static and non-static methods of proper classes (`type ...`), but the result is the same.

If however I apply it to a custom indexer, like so

```
type Dummy =
    member self.Item
        with [<MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)>] get x = x + 1
```

the resulting IL is

```
.method public hidebysig specialname instance int32 get_Item(int32 x) cil managed
{
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImplAttribute::.ctor(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImplOptions) = ( 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 ) 
    .maxstack  8
    IL_0000:  nop
    IL_0001:  ldarg.1
    IL_0002:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_0003:  add
    IL_0004:  ret
}
```

... though I'm not sure whether that is equivalent to the "aggressiveinling" flag generated by the C# compiler.

Is that behavior desired/expected? Is it a bug in the F# compiler?

(Note: I'm aware of the F# `inline` keyword, but that only works for F# clients of my library, not C# consumers.)

Comment: AFAIK this attribute is used by the JIT:er to hint that the method should be inlined. So if that is correct you should check the generate machine code. Note; it's not as simple as viewing disassembly in .NET as with debugger running the JIT:er is much less aggressive.

Comment: Awww, I see what you mean. It seems to missing in the IL meta data. Let me check this later.

Comment: It looks like only `PreserveSig`, `Synchronized`, and `NoInlining` are respected - see `ComputeMethodImplAttribs` in [IlxGen.fs](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/IlxGen.fs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@kvb is correct that it seems the `F#` compiler seems to strip out the `MethodImpl`.

`ComputeMethodImplAttribs` in [IlxGen.fs](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/IlxGen.fs) is called to compute the method attributes.

```
and ComputeMethodImplAttribs cenv (_v:Val) attrs =
    let implflags = 
        match TryFindFSharpAttribute cenv.g cenv.g.attrib_MethodImplAttribute attrs with
        | Some (Attrib(_,_,[ AttribInt32Arg flags ],_,_,_,_))  -> flags
        | _ -> 0x0

    let hasPreserveSigAttr = 
        match TryFindFSharpAttributeOpt cenv.g cenv.g.attrib_PreserveSigAttribute attrs with
        | Some _ -> true
        | _ -> false

    // strip the MethodImpl pseudo-custom attribute    
    // The following method implementation flags are used here
    // 0x80 - hasPreserveSigImplFlag
    // 0x20 - synchronize
    // (See ECMA 335, Partition II, section 23.1.11 - Flags for methods [MethodImplAttributes]) 
    let attrs = attrs 
                    |> List.filter (IsMatchingFSharpAttribute cenv.g cenv.g.attrib_MethodImplAttribute >> not) 
                        |> List.filter (IsMatchingFSharpAttributeOpt cenv.g cenv.g.attrib_PreserveSigAttribute >> not)
    let hasPreserveSigImplFlag = ((implflags &&& 0x80) <> 0x0) || hasPreserveSigAttr
    let hasSynchronizedImplFlag = (implflags &&& 0x20) <> 0x0
    let hasNoInliningImplFlag = (implflags &&& 0x08) <> 0x0
    hasPreserveSigImplFlag, hasSynchronizedImplFlag, hasNoInliningImplFlag, attrs
```

Looking more closely around row: 4990:

```
    let attrs = attrs 
                    |> List.filter (IsMatchingFSharpAttribute cenv.g cenv.g.attrib_MethodImplAttribute >> not) 
                        |> List.filter (IsMatchingFSharpAttributeOpt cenv.g cenv.g.attrib_PreserveSigAttribute >> not)
```

The first `filter` filters away `MethodImplAttribute`.

Now, I was looking a bit trying to find the rationale but this code stems back to `latkin` initial commit. I do think it's probably wrong to strip away the `MethodImpl` especially for `AggressiveInlining` which I believe affects the JIT:ing therefore it needs to be in the assembly.

I would recommend registering an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/visualfsharp/issues). Perhaps you can get an explaination at least.

Comment: Filtering out the attribute makes sense because it's really a pseudo-custom-attribute and shouldn't be present as an actual custom attribute in the metadata (see e.g. http://weblog.ikvm.net/2008/11/25/PseudoCustomAttributes.aspx).

Comment: I'll open an issue on the GitHub repo.

Comment: That doesn't seem like the correct place to put the attribute. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20517103/methodimplaggressiveinlining-how-aggressive-is-it

Comment: The issue on GitHub can be found at: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/1637